# SwiftUI View not Updating when an Array in a Class has updated

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Im having trouble getting the view to update to reflect each new entityPosArray that is passed in from a WebSocket reply.
It updates in this Class but not in the View, and I am out of ideas to test.

I think its around the line "entityPositionClassArray = entityPosArray" which is not registering as @ObservedObject update?
It does work if I use a button action to trigger EntityPositions() but im after a live view update on each updated Array passed in.

sample entityPosArray:

```
[["EntID": "0012", "entPOSX": "1064.55", "entPOSY": "871.31"], 
["EntID": "5699", "entPOSX": "2231.13", "entPOSY": "1962.92"], 
["EntID": "5540", "entPOSX": "-1619.95", "entPOSY": "-1344.04"], 
["EntID": "5989", "entPOSY": "731.11", "entPOSX": "-1689.66"], 
["EntID": "0809", "entPOSX": "-971.65", "entPOSY": "-1761.38"]]
```

So far have just been trying to get the array.count to update in the view, after that the rest should be simular.
I can see the data in console update from the Class but do not see a View reload or Text field update.

````
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation


class EntityPositionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var entityPositionClassArray = [[String:String]]()
    @Published var entityOnline: Int = 0
    
    func EntityPositions() {
        entityPositionClassArray = entityPosArray
        entityOnline = entityPositionClassArray.count           // Added to test in console
        let _ = print("There are \(entityOnline) connected")    // <- This works on each Array update
    }
}


struct EntityOnline: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model = EntityPositionViewModel()
    
    init() {
        model.EntityPositions()                 // init() makes no difference
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test: \(model.entityOnline)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            // Testing for View Update and Reload
            let entityOnline2 = model.entityPositionClassArray.count // Checking different call
            let _ = print("TestEnts: \(entityOnline2)")
            let _ = print("View Reloaded")
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: you are not calling `EntityPositions()` anywhere in the view, except for init (btw in swift, functions names don't start with capital). So why do you expect view to get updated? also `func EntityPositions()` definition is invalid: `entityPositionClassArray = entityPosArray` <-- what is `entityPosArray`?

Answer (score 0):

As @5318223 has called out, you're not making a call to your model anywhere that would trigger an update, so why are you expecting one?

You could try removing the `init` method from your `View` struct and replacing it with an `onAppear` modifier which would trigger view updates.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation


class EntityPositionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var entityPositionClassArray = [[String:String]]()
    @Published var entityOnline: Int = 0
    
    func EntityPositions() {
        entityPositionClassArray = entityPosArray
        entityOnline = entityPositionClassArray.count           // Added to test in console
        let _ = print("There are \(entityOnline) connected")    // <- This works on each Array update
    }
}


struct EntityOnline: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model = EntityPositionViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test: \(model.entityOnline)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            // Testing for View Update and Reload
            let entityOnline2 = model.entityPositionClassArray.count // Checking different call
            let _ = print("TestEnts: \(entityOnline2)")
            let _ = print("View Reloaded")
        }.onAppear {
                model.EntityPositions()
        }
    }
}
```

This would however be called on every appearance of the view so might not be what you're after. Generally you would have a button on your `View` that would trigger some sort of state update on your view model like below:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count: Int = 0

    func didTapButton() {
        count += 1
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Count is: \(viewModel.count)")
        Button("Increase Count") {
            viewModel.didTapButton()
        }
    }
}
```

Notice as well that I've used a `StateObject` as the `View` in this case is what is creating the `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the onAppear idea didn't work.
I have had a button there at times to test updates but working towards a live update from @ObservedObject as the data from the websocket updates every 5-10sec.
As you both have mentioned that I need a call from the view to the model somewhere, which was the original idea of the init. But as this is the 1st try at this style of app Im still learning so onwards and upwards.

Comment: If you're using an `@ObseverdObject` and you have an `@Published` object which the `View` class consumes, then there is no reason that view updates should not be triggered. Whether it be from a button or some sort of timer/event trigger, the `View` would still get updated. In the example I gave above, the `View` consumes `ViewModel.count` which is `@Published` so triggers a reload.